# USB mouse does not work on some ports

Tags: mouse

Laptop: Lenovo Ideapad Z570, 
OS: ubuntu 12.04

USB mouse works only if connected via USB port on left side of the laptop. Does not work if connected via USB ports on right side. My laptop has 2 usb ports on right side.

Could anyone let me know how to troubleshoot this problem.

Comment: This is only a guess, but the isolated usb port might be usb 3.0, while the group of two would then be usb 2.0, (or vice-versa). Some devices may have [backwards] compatibility issues that cause these kind of problems :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list USB ports which are satisfying devices.

```
lsusb
```

and

```
sudo lshw |grep -i usb
```

for assure of all port available on your Ubuntu.